# Create a curved grid for threejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, three.js

I want to create a grid of, let's say 500x500, and I want it to be able to be curved in certain places (think of it as space-time plane that's curved due to gravity). I'm stuck at the start.

This is what I found on the documentation:

```
// Create a sine-like wave
const curve = new THREE.SplineCurve( [
    new THREE.Vector2( -10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( -5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 5, -5 ),
    new THREE.Vector2( 10, 0 )
] );

const points = curve.getPoints( 50 );
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );

const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );

// Create the final object to add to the scene
const splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
```

I think this should be working but it doesn't. I don't know how to create a multiple lines from here. I tried to handle some array but I didn't know where or how. I have done my research but I can't make any headway.

---

I have another question: Is that this is a `Vector2` I need to make it 3d for that work? There a lot of other classes like `CatmullRomCurve3`, `CubicBezierCurve3`, etc, but the problem still is that i need to make an array to create all the vectors and lines.

--
EDIT i created a code for the grid lines but the curve probleme still the same

```
    let size = 12, step = 1;
    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    // create a simple square shape. We duplicate the top left and bottom right
    // vertices because each vertex needs to appear once per triangle.
    const vertices = [];
    for(var i = - size; i <= size; i += step) {
      vertices.push( - size, - 0.4, i);
      vertices.push( size, - 0.4, i);

      vertices.push( i, - 0.4, - size);
      vertices.push( i, - 0.4, size);
    }
    
    let positionAttribute = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3);
    geometry.setAttribute("position", positionAttribute);
   
    let lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial());
```

Comment: Well i figured out how to make the grid with multiple lines, but the probleme still the same i cant found how to curve them :

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Regardless, let's see what we can do. Can you please attatch a picture of what you are trying to achieve?